# Grizzly HttpServer: Set permanent header for every response

Tags: java, cors, grizzly

I am using a Grizzly HttpServer and i want to add a specific header in every response. Specifically, i want to avoid [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problems by adding an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

So, ideally, i want something like this:

```
HttpServer server = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, crc);
server.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*");
```

Generally, i am looking for a solution that does not require that i have to manually insert this header in every request-response action.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There is no such a way at the moment, but you can file a request for improvement at https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY and we'll take care of that ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alexey said, there is no way (from the current Grizzly Server version) to do this. If anyone finds something else that works, i will gladly confirm it as an accepted answer.

The best alternative that works quite well is to extend the 'ContainerResponseFilter' class and override the 'filter' method.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894430/configure-response-object-for-rest-services-inside-a-jersey-grizzly-server-in-o/28894909#28894909) for 1.x API

Here is an [example](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/) for 2.x API (minor changes)